# Dummy variable with 2 classes. Should it be in a single or multiple columns?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on a classification problem, using a logistic regression model in Python (scikit learn). One of my features is gender. In the original dataset, this variable is a string (male, female). I used the get_dummies method from pandas and it created 2 columns with 0,1 values. One for each class.

My question is, should I use 2 different columns, or a single column like male (0,1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally like to use a `n - 1` columns for a field with `n` categories. When using the [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) method this means setting `drop_first` to True.

As far as why I like to do this; a former instructor of mine explains it pretty well in his answer to [one hot encoding vs dummy encoding in sckikit learn](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/224055/85955). Basically it boils down to eliminating collinearity.